# extract each value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a string like this and I have to extract values from it.

```
process({ "www.google.com": { "target": "google.com", "0": [ 94, 71 ], "1": [ 94, 71 ], "2": [ 94, 71 ], "4": [ 93, 67 ], "categories": { "501": 99, "301": 47, "304": 5 } } } )
```

I wanted to access the values like `"0": [94, 71]`, `"categories": { "501": 99, "301": 47, "304": 5 }`, etc.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on
[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a
[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: post what you have tried so far?

Comment: `['www.googl.com']['0']` and `['www.google.com']['categories']`, etc.

Comment: Is that a string?

Comment: yes.. its just a string.. i tried to take the values out from the "Process" using for loop but i got the reply like

Comment: yes.. its just a string.. i tried to take the values out from the "Process" using for loop but i got the reply like "p r o c e s s ( {   " w w w . g o o g l e . c o m " :   {   " t a r g e t " :   " g o o g l e . c o".. i want to take the values out from process()

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
import ast

a = """process({ "www.google.com": { "target": "google.com", "0": [ 94, 71 ], "1": [ 94, 71 ], "2": [ 94, 71 ], "4": [ 93, 67 ], "categories": { "501": 99, "301": 47, "304": 5 } } } )
"""

d = ast.literal_eval(re.findall(r'{.*}', a)[0])
print d, '\n'
print d['www.google.com']['0'], '\n'
print d['www.google.com']['categories']
```

Output:

```
{'www.google.com': {'target': 'google.com', '1': [94, 71], '0': [94, 71], '2': [94, 71], '4': [93, 67], 'categories': {'301': 47, '304': 5, '501': 99}}} 

[94, 71] 

{'301': 47, '304': 5, '501': 99}
```

Comment: You can go one step further with `ast.literal_eval(ast.parse(a).body[0].value.args[0])`.

Comment: @bereal How to look inside each of the steps whats happening internally?

Comment: Just dissect it between dots, like `ast.parse(a).body` is a list of `_ast.Expr` etc.